# Limit of a product of two functions is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ two real valued functions such that $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)$ exists and is finite, $g(x)$ is bounded and $$\lim_{x\to c}f(x) g(x) =0$$
> then prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=0$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)=0$ or both.

My try: let $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)\neq 0$ then
$$\lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x) =\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x) g(x)   }{\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)   }$$ and hence we have $$\lim_{x\to c} g(x) =0  $$

What if $\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)\neq 0$?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest to proceed from the definition by contradiction.

Comment: @user Can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: suppose by contradiction $f\to a\neq 0$ and $g\to b \neq 0$ then use the definition of limit for $fg$

Comment: @user But $g$ is just bounded. How can we assume that $g\to b$?

Comment: Ah ok sorry, anyway the same idea applies. Take $f\to a\neq 0$ and apply the definition for $fg$, assuming by contradiction $fg\to 0$.

Comment: @user I am sorry. I cannot understand that how to use the definition for $fg$.

Comment: What does it mean that $fg\to 0$?

Comment: You need to use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition for limit.

Comment: @user It means that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)g(x)-0|<\epsilon$ when $|x-c|<\delta$. What should we note from here?

Comment: In you try, you just proved that: if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\ne 0$ then $\lim_{x\to c}g(x) = 0$. Together with the other case that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0$, you already proved the statement in the question. If you really want to know what if $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\ne 0$ or this limit doesn't exist, by the contraposition of your try, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=0$.

Comment: @jazz we show that if $g$ is bounded with $g\not\to 0$ then we reach a contradiction

Comment: The case $g\to 0$ can be easily handled separately.

Comment: @peterwhy Can you please write as an answer?

Comment: @user How do we get a contradiction when $g$ is bounded with $g$ not converging to $0$?

Comment: We just need to set $\varepsilon$ out of that bound, this exists otherwise we should have $g\to 0$.

Comment: @user I am really confused. I would request you to write an answer.

Comment: @Jazz I rewrote my comment as an answer, from your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0$ then we are done.

So suppose $\neg(\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0).\ $ Since $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)\ $ **exists**, let $b = \lim_{x\to c} f(x)\neq 0.$

By definition, $ \exists\ u>0$ such that $\ f(w) \in \left(\frac{b}{2}, \frac{3b}{2}\right)\quad \forall\ w\in (c-u,\ c+u).$

Suppose further that $\neg\left(\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)=0\right)\ $ and let $\ \varepsilon > 0.\ $

Then there exists $d>0\ $ such that for every $\ \delta>0,\ \exists\ \delta'\in (c-\delta,\ c+\delta)\ $ such that $\ \vert g(\delta') \vert > d. $

In particular, for every $\ \delta>0,\ \exists\ \delta'\in (c-u,\ c+u)\ $ such that $\ \vert g(\delta') \vert > d. $

Thus, for every $\ \delta>0,\ \exists\ \delta'\in (c-u,\ c+u)\ $ such that $\ \vert f(\delta')g(\delta') \vert > \frac{db}{2},\ $ proving that $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)g(x)\neq0.$

Comment: @Jazz That’s the way I would suggest for a solution to really capture what is going on.

Comment: Excellent solution. +1

Comment: Excuse me Adam, why do you need all this? Please read my proof which is clear, short and simple!

Comment: "Excuse me Adam, why do you need all this?" In my opinion your proof is not dramatically shorter... Our proofs are different and both are fine. My one opens up the bonnet and shows you exactly what is going on. In yours the bonnet is closed but you get the job done...

Answer (score 1):

Let  $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}f(x)=l\neq\,0$. Write

$f(x)g(x)=(f(x)-l+l)g(x)=(f(x)-l)g(x)+lg(x)$. It is clear that :

$|(f(x)-l)g(x)|\leq\,M\,|f(x)-l|$ and clearly $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}(f(x)-l)g(x)=0$.

Therefore $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}l\,g(x)=0$. Thus $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}\,g(x)=0$.

Now if $l=0$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}f(x)=0$.

And clearly we can have both $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}\,f(x)=0$ and

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}\,g(x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. How did you get since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}(f(x)-l)g(x)=0$, therefore $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}l\,g(x)=0$? You are using sum of limits is limit of the sum. But this requires the limit to exist and finite

Comment: But I just use your assumptions that $limf(x)g(x)=0$ , $limf(x)=l$ exists and that $g(x)$ is bounded. Read my proof carefully! If $limf(x)g(x)=0$ and $lim(f(x)-l)g(x)=0$ then obviously as the difference of limits $limlg(x)=0$ and $limg(x)=0$

Comment: The answers which got upvotes are just making things complicated for no reason. My proof is the shortest and simplest!

Comment: I agree this is a good alternative proof. You could write the first few lines alternatively as follows using the triangle inequality: $\ \vert l\vert \vert g(x)\vert =\ \vert lg(x)\vert = \vert f(x)g(x)+(f(x)-l)g(x)\vert \leq \vert f(x)g(x)\vert + \vert f(x)-l \vert\ \vert g(x)\vert\ \leq  \vert f(x)g(x)\vert + M \vert f(x)-l \vert.\ $ Taking limits as $x\to c,\ $ we get that $g(x)\to 0\ $ as $x\to c.$

Comment: Yes, this follows the same logic! It is nice!

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases, depending on $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ (which exists and is finite):

- If $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=0$.
- If $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)\ne0$, then in your try, you already proved that $\lim_{x\to c} g(x) = 0$:

  $$
  \lim_{x\to c} g(x) = \frac{\lim_{x\to c} f(x)g(x)}{\lim_{x\to c} f(x)}
  = 0
  $$

Either way, $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=0$ or $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)=0$ (or both).

If you really want to know what if $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\ne 0$ or this limit doesn't exist, by the contrapositive of your try, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if $\lim_{x\to c } g(x)\neq 0$ or this limit doesn't exist then how by contraposition of my try $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=0$?

Comment: @Jazz Because you proved that: if $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)\ne0$ then $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)=0$. The contrapositive would be: if $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)\ne0$ or this limit doesn't exist, then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks again. I understood that if $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\neq 0$ then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=0$. But how do we get if $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ does not exist then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=0$ ?

Comment: @Jazz There are $3$ cases for $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$: 1) exists and $=0$, 2) exists and $\ne 0$, or 3) doesn't exist. The negation of $\lim_{x\to c} g(x) = 0$ is "$\lim_{x\to c} g(x)\ne 0$ or this limit doesn't exist". Then follow the contrapositive, not "$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) \ne 0$", i.e. $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem: if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} b(x)=b$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} a(x)=a\neq 0,$ then $$\lim_{x\to c}{b(x)\over a(x)}={b\over a}$$
Assume $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=a\neq 0.$ Then substituting $a(x)=f(x)$ and $b(x)=f(x)g(x)$ we get $b=0$ and $$\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\lim_{x\to c}{b(x)\over a(x)}={b\over a}=0$$